# Prometheus query based on time of the day

Tags: prometheus

Is there any option in Prometheus query to check if the current time is in day or night? I mean to set the threshold different in day and in the night:

```
sum(irate(haproxy_frontend_http_responses_total{code=~"5xx"}[5m]) > 10) # 
for night

sum(irate(haproxy_frontend_http_responses_total{code=~"5xx"}[5m]) > 100) # for day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prometheus in-built `time()` function to get the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.

There is another function called `hour()` that could also come in handy

Detailed documentation: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#time